# How to add font awesome using ASP.NET.Core Angular template

Tags: angular, webpack, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm using the NET.Core 2.0 Angular template, which work with webpack, angular-cli, angular component, typescript.

I did:

**command line** - Install package and loader

```
npm install --save font-awesome
npm install url-loader --save-dev
```

**webpack.config.js** - add loader rule

```
    module: {
        rules: [
             ...
            { test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: "url-loader" },
            { test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: "url-loader" }
        ]
    },
```

**my.component.css** - Import to my component

```
@import '~font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css';
```

**my.component.html** - Put the icon

```
<i class="fa fa-check fa-6"></i>
```

---

Now I got no error message but still can't see the icon.

Did I do anything wrong?

Comment: This isn't anything to do with Angular or ASP.Net Core, it's just plain CSS. You can't use `~` in the import, try: `@import '/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css';`

Comment: I keep getting this error
`Error: Cannot find module "-!../../../../node_modules/css-loader/index.js!./font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css"
at webpackMissingModule` but with `~` is OK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you guys for your help~

Eventually I fixed the issue by updating the **webpack.config.js** to:

```
module: {
  loaders: [
    {
        test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
        loader: "url-loader"
    },
    {
        test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
        loader: "url-loader"
    }
  ]
}
```

rather than put it in the `rules: [...]`

It's weird that `rules` won't work...but anyway~ :P

Answer (score 11):

This is for .NET Core 2, after you create a SPA Project using `dotnet new angular`:

1. Go to the root of the project and install the package: `npm install font-awesome --save`. You should now see it in `package.json` dependencies.
2. After that go to `webpack.config.vendor.js` and add font awesome to the array under non tree shakable modules:

   ```
   const nonTreeShakableModules = [
       'bootstrap',
       'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css',
       'es6-promise',
       'es6-shim',
       'event-source-polyfill',
       'font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css',
       'jquery',
   ];
   ```
3. Now we need to tell the webpack that we added this new package. So if you haven't done so before install this in the root of project with `npm install --save-dev npm-install-webpack-plugin`.
4. Finally, run this command in the root of project: `webpack --config webpack.config.vendor.js`

Comment: Thank you so much! I was ripping my hair out. I did not have to do step 3, just step 4.

Comment: FYI - my above comment is for webpack version 2.5.1.

Comment: I had to install webpack globally `npm install -g webpack` for #4 to work for me. I also had to remember to rebuild my app and F5 to see the changes in the browser.

Comment: None of these worked for me.  I started with a fresh angular template.  I've added the .css entry to the nonTreeShakableModules array.  I then ran step 3, which gave me an error.  So I tried step 4 (with and without global webpack installation), and I get "missing script: webpack".

Comment: I don't have webpack.config.vendor.js after `dotnet new angular`. Can I simply make one?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I am the only one who installed font-awesome like `npm install fontawesome --save`?  Well, it should have been like `npm install font-awesome --save`. Dammit!